# How to convert a base64 string to SVG in python?

Tags: python, flask, svg, jinja2, qr-code

I'm using [flask-qrcode](https://marcoagner.github.io/Flask-QRcode/) to render a QR code (it is the only plugin I've found that enables overlaid icons). Following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/two-factor-authentication-with-flask) tutorial, my function is within a route:

```
@app.route('/qr', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qr():
    return QRcode.qrcode("data", error_correction='H', icon_img='icon.png')
```

However, because the flask-qrcode plugin is designed to be rendered directly in Jinja2 templates, this means that my QRcode function returns a string which is rendered in the browser like this:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjoAAAI6CAY...

So, my question is, what do I need to add to my python route function to return an SVG image instead of a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is, what do I need to add to my python route function to return an SVG image instead of a string?

Render the qrcode using the SVG image factory, [as explained in the library's documentation](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode#svg).

Here you're using the default factory, it renders to a PNG which can't really be converted to SVG (while rasterising a vector image is a pretty standard operation, vectorising raster images tend to yield sub-par results).

Comment: I tried the base64 method you suggested but am getting this: '�PNG  IHDR�=&�KIDATx���Q��\�Q�2�0I�.... ' I'll try the SVG factory method now.

Comment: You're right and I've reluctantly had to switch to pyqrcode, even though it doesn't have any icon overlay functionality. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JackPutter it looks like flask-qrcode just uses the regular qrcode to render to a PIL image, then merges the icon in there. So you could probably do that as well. Doing so for SVG is both more complicated (can't use PIL) and simpler (an SVG is "just" an XML document so it's a matter or finding the right way to embed a raster image as the place where you want it).